# how to pivot /transpose rows of a column in to individual columns in spark-scala without using the pivot method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Please check below image for the reference to my use case

[image]

Comment: Please click on the link for the reference to my use case.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the same result without using pivot by adding the columns manually, if you know all the names of the new columns:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, when}

dataframe
  .withColumn("cheque", when(col("ttype") === "cheque", col("tamt")))
  .withColumn("draft", when(col("ttype") === "draft", col("tamt")))
  .drop("tamt", "ttype")
```

As this solution does not trigger shuffle, your processing will be faster than using pivot.

It can be generalized if you don't know the name of the columns. However, in this case you should benchmark to check whether pivot is more performant:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, when}

val newColumnNames = dataframe.select("ttype").distinct.collect().map(_.getString(0))

newColumnNames
  .foldLeft(dataframe)((df, columnName) => {
    df.withColumn(columnName, when(col("ttype") === columnName, col("tamt")))
  })
  .drop("tamt", "ttype")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vincent, very nicely articulated and its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy`,`pivot` & `agg` functions. Check below code.
Added inline comments.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------+------+----+
|tdate     |ttype |tamt|
+----------+------+----+
|2020-10-15|draft |5000|
|2020-10-18|cheque|7000|
+----------+------+----+
```

```
scala> df
.groupBy($"tdate") // Grouping data based on tdate column.
.pivot("ttype",Seq("cheque","draft")) // pivot based on ttype and "draft","cheque" are new column name
.agg(first("tamt")) // aggregation by "tamt" column.
.show(false)

+----------+------+-----+
|tdate     |cheque|draft|
+----------+------+-----+
|2020-10-18|7000  |null |
|2020-10-15|null  |5000 |
+----------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks Srinivas for your answer could you give a clarity on use of First method in the above code,what it exactly does?